# how to create a link to a website in XML that displays custom text

Tags: android, android-xml

Good evening,

I have a quick question that should be pretty easy, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

I have a link to a web page that I want to put in my app. I want to do it in XML in order to make things a little easier for me because this will be a quite large app. I want the like to be custom text that when clicked opens up the web browser. I guess just like you can with HTML. Right now I have

```
android:text="http://bhflc.org/"
android:autoLink="web"
```

I understand that the text part is where my custom text needs to be, but where would I put the web address?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDEA:**

You need a custom web view class . In this web view you can get attribute values which you set from xml file.

**CODE:**

Your webview class

```
    YourWebView extends WebView{
    public YourWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       //get attribute values which you set from xml file.
       TypedArray a=mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrSet, R.styleable.YourView);
       final String url=a.getString( R.styleable.YourView_web_url);
       yourWebView.mWebView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yourpackagenamspace.yourView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    app:web_url="http://bhflc.org/" 
     />
```

You must declare your attributes with values/attrs.xml file

```
<declare-styleable name="YourView">

        <attr name="web_url" format="string" />

    </declare-styleable>
```

Comment: so there is no way to do this completely in XML?

Comment: what is your problem using above way?

Comment: so much to edit. My app is already fairly large. I guess I can do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TextView on XML and set it clickable:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textViewID"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Link"
     android:clickable="true" />
```

And in your Class you can put something like this:

```
TextView LinkButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewID);
LinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.link.com");
                            Intent openBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            startActivity(openBrowser);
        }
    });
```

I don't know anyway to do it only throught XML.